# Cannot find the right nuget package to include for CosmosDBTrigger

Tags: database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to develop an azure function that triggers off an insert/update in the collection. From the azure webjobs sdk documentation, my best bet is a CosmosDBTrigger function. However, I am getting a compilation error when I create a CosmosDBTrigger function using the Visual Studio "azure functions" extension. It looks like the vsix for CosmosDBTrigger does not automatically include the nuget package references for the CosmosDBTrigger class.

Has anyone used Visual Studio 2017 to create an azure function triggered from a ChangeFeed item?

**Update:** When I tried to inlude Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Extensions, I get the following error.

```
NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.11 requires Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions (= 2.1.0) but version Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions 3.0.0-beta5 was resolved.
NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue. 
    Accelerator.Feed Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions 3.0.0-beta5 -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (>= 3.0.0-beta5) 
    Accelerator.Feed -> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.11 -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (= 2.1.0).
Package restore failed.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Azure Cosmos DB bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb), you'll need NuGet package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB`

> The Cosmos DB bindings for Functions version 1.x are provided in the [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB) NuGet package. For Functions 2.x, the package is [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB).